# Custom authentication with foreign model in Rails 4 with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a typical **User** model (with username, email and password fields) that **has_one Client** model that **has many** Phone models.

What I want to do is allow the user to sign in with a combination of either email + password, username + password or one of the phone numbers + password.

How can I achieve this using Devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this I had to add the following to my **User** model:

```
  attr_accessor :login

  private

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      match = where(conditions).where(
        ["lower(email) = :login OR lower(username) = :login",
         { login: login.downcase }]).first

      unless match
        match = joins(client: :phones).where(conditions).where(
          ["lower(client_phones.number) = :phone",
           { phone: PhoneFormatter.parse(login) }]).first
      end

      find(match.id) if match
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
```